# Updating Schema for Mongoengine

Tags: mongoengine

If I have a document like:

```
class Page(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

and I want to update it to:

```
class Page(Document):
    page_title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

what is the best way to handle the database migration in mongoengine?  I would imagine you could iterate through the database and pull the objects that have that field and add them back in with the new field then drop all objects that have that field, but it'd be nice if there was an idiomatic way to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: There are no migrations in mongoengine as far as I know. All I found was an example of pseudo-migration by Ross Lawley: https://gist.github.com/rozza/3379016

Comment: ya it seems like you just manually update the database with a $rename

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way to do it would be by a two-step change of the class. 
First add the new field and remove the "required" constraint:

```
class Page(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=200)
    page_title = String(max_length=200)
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Then run the following commands:

```
for page in Page.objects():
    page.page_title = page.title
    page.save()
Page.objects.update(unset__title=1) ## Unset the title field of the documents
```

That will update the documents of your DB without having to drop them (which is useful because they will keep the same id).

Then you make the final modification to your class, as you wanted:

```
class Page(Document):
    page_title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```